# Django : How to associate a user to a created post when post is created through a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've created a normal Django posts app, which basically let's users create posts and it's content.
Now the thing is that I implemented the create post form as a `ModelForm` in forms.py. Now if it wasn't a `ModelForm` and just a html-form, I would have used `request.POST.get('data')`
But now I use

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = (
        'title',
        'content',
        'image',
    )
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

Views.py

```
def create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
    return render(request,'create.html',{'form':form})
```

How can I relate a user to a created post?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply assign the user to the instance in between the two save functions:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.user = request.user
instance.save()
```

Comment: You sure? That i dont have to make any changes in forms.py , cause after what you said , it says user is not defined

Comment: Actually i also added `if user is not None and user.is_active:` to avoid anonymous users, then its saying user is not defined