# Alter Django Form

Tags: python, django

How can i adjust my code so that a user cannot choose another user for a new post. I want to make it so that the logged in user is automatically added as the author.

I have tried setting the fields part in the views.py to just the content field, however it doesn't work

**models.py**

```
class post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

**views.py**

```
class CreatePostView(CreateView):

    model = post
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'users/create.html'
```

**Myform.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: Logged in user will be only able to access his model instance. Did you includ the LoginRequiredMixin in your view?

Comment: I will try that now

Comment: @VisheshMangla I tried adding that before 'CreateView', however it still lets me choose other authors

Comment: I would suggest you to use function based views.

Comment: There might be better ways, but this is the solution I know https://stackoverflow.com/a/53283530/813946

Comment: I will try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CreatePostView(CreateView):
    model = post
    template_name = 'users/create.html'
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually insert the user value using `request.user.username`
(or)
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940623/how-to-do-i-automatically-set-the-user-field-to-current-user-in-django-modelform). The questioner's answer is located at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you need to do:

1. Protect the page, so that anonymous users cannot access it, Using `LoginRequiredMixin`
2. Remove the user from the fields
3. Enter the current user in the submitted form after the form is posted, using `form_valid` method

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ["content"]
    template_name = "create.html"
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```